# постоянная запись в канал

Tags: golang

Реализовать постоянную запись данных в канал (главный поток). Реализовать набор из N воркеров, которые читают произвольные данные из канала и выводят в stdout.

Я начал с того что хотел записать значение в канал и запустить тестово несколько воркеров которые это значение выведут

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func Worker(ch chan int64, ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            data, ok := <-ch
            if !ok {
                println("channel closed")
                return
            }
            println(data, "saved")
        default:
            println(<-ch)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int64)
    ctx, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go Worker(ch, ctx, nil)
    }
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            cancel()
            log.Println("CANCEL")
            return
        default:
            ch <- time.Now().Unix()
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Значение из канала можно взять только один раз. Чтобы взять еще одно такое же значение - его надо __снова__ передать в канал.

Comment: @u_mulder а как-то можно вообще запустить пул воркеров с одним значением? Как его прочитать и поместить разные горутины?

Comment: Не очень понятно - почему с __одним-то__ значением? Изначально ж задача стоит - есть канал в которой постоянно кто-то пишет, и надо создать пул воркеров, которые читают инфу из канала. В каждое прочтение воркер получает текущее доступное значение из канала, то есть __нет нигде__ указания что, __все__ воркеры получают одно и то же значение. Пул воркеров и нужен чтобы разгребать канал по мере получения сообщений, а не для того чтобы всем воркерам выдать одно и то же. Это как мешки разгружать - все грузчики подходят к куче, хватают каждый по мешку и несут. А не раздается всем копия мешка.

Comment: @u_mulder ваш комментарий можно понять как "вы корректно сделали воркера, осталось только сымитировать запись из разных источников".))

Comment: не понятно — нужно одно значение сразу во всех горутинах или нет? У меня была такая задача и понимаю, почему так может быть нужно... но нужно ли вам?

Comment: @MaksimFedorov нужно чтобы было одно, как описал u_mulder.

Comment: Ну оберните вы int64 и передавйте в канал структуру, в нее добавьте счетчик, сколько раз та была обработана и читайте воркером из канала, если счетчик ниже необходимного, то толкайте опять в канал.